# Is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ equal to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Here $\mathcal{B}(E)$ denotes the power set of $E$, and $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ the product of the $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. We know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275375/40263) might help you further.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.